# obtener ruta de la carpeta original a través de su archivo directo .lnk JAVA 5

Tags: java

El problema es el siguiente:

Intento crear un archivo PDF en la ruta especificada por el usuario
Para obtener tal ruta, utilizo el JFileChooser
Este le permite al usuario, elegir carpetas para guardar el fichero que son archivos directos.
Los path de estas carpetas contienen la extensión .lnk y, al pasarle este al generador de PDF, me dice que no existe la ubicación.

Entonces el problema es como a partir del path del archivo directo encontrar la carpeta que hace referencia, para obtener la ubicación original y poder pasársela al generador de PDF.

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación hecha en java 5, por lo que no puedo usar librerías nuevas. Se agradece cualquier ayuda o idea, Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Segun investigue los archivos .lnk son los accesos directos de la plataforma [windows](/questions/tagged/windows).

Java no ofrece nada en su documentación al respecto, así que deberás usar alguna librería externa como [jacob](/questions/tagged/jacob), que a su vez esta basada en [jni](/questions/tagged/jni) para hacer llamadas de sistema.

Su repositorio de github es [este](https://github.com/freemansoft/jacob-project).